# Access VBA Richtext in tables and forms

Tags: ms-access, vba

I cut and pasted the following into a text box on a form:
Corrective action: how do you improve perfection?

then I press an "update the database" button, strip the words "Corrective action:", and place the remaining text in a table.

In the table, the entry looks like this: how do you improve perfection?

when I post the information back out to the form, the operating system (or something) inserts a blank row under it.

It doesn't take long of repeating the above steps until the textbox gets unacceptably large because of the blank rows being added to the text.

How can I get rid of this blank row that is being inserted? I don't see any extra characters other than what is shown here.

This question is related to the "CRLFs in ACCESS TABLES" question that I posted on 30 September 2016.

27 Feb 2017
This morning I used the following code to look at the last few characters in the string:

```
theFld.Value = Trim(tempNom)
'temporary
tempCt = Len(tempNom)
While tempCt > 0
    Debug.Print Asc(tempNom)
    tempNom = right(tempNom, Len(tempNom) - 1)
    tempCt = Len(tempNom)
    If tempCt < 15 Then Stop
Wend
'temporary
```

Either with or without the TRIM function, the debugger showed no unexpected characters, yet it still is inserting CRLFs! Interesting, the debugger is putting in a blank line at the end of the debug.print out, but the subroutine shows no character for it.

Comment: If you are not somehow entering those characters (any VBA code involved?), then on your form, look at the textbox property 'Enter Key Behavior'.... what is it set to?

Comment: To find records that have either a CR or LF, run a query similar to following (Change table name and field name!):  SELECT FldB, InStr(1,[FLDB],Chr(13)) AS CR, InStr(1,[FLDB],Chr(10)) AS LF
FROM Table1
WHERE (((InStr(1,[FLDB],Chr(13)))>0)) OR (((InStr(1,[FLDB],Chr(10)))>0));

Comment: Key behavior set to "Default". thank you for the input

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is all to do with how you're selecting the text to cut and where you're cutting it from. If you select a line of text from the middle of a Word document, you might notice what looks like a space at the end of this line in the selection. This is actually the 'new line' character(s). So when you paste into Access you get the new line as well. You don't see this by default in table view because table view is usually set to single row height, but if you edit this entry in the table you can go beyond the end of your text and down to the next line. This is most obvious if you use shift-F2 to bring up the zoom box to edit.

There are a couple of ways to cure this problem:

1 Be careful when selecting the text to cut. If you click and drag your mouse well beyond the end of what you want to copy, you might find that Word is automatically selecting whole words as you expand the selection. Once you've gone past where you want the end of your selection to be, if you start moving slowly back to that end position Word will start de-selecting a character at a time rather than whole words. Make sure you select only up to the last letter of what you want and don't include the 'space' (new line) after your text.

2 Alternatively, select text in the way that you have always done, but when you paste you might notice that the insertion point ends up on the line after your inserted text. Just press the backspace to get rid of this new line.

3 If this is something that other users are doing and you can't 'educate' them into how to cut/paste without including the new line at the end of the text, then you're going to have to strip trailing new line off in the code behind your 'update the database' button. I can never remember which way round the CR and LF characters go, but it will be something like

```
Dim strCA As String
If Right(txtCorrectiveAction, 2) = Chr(10) & Chr(13) Then  'might need to swap the 10 and 13 around
    strCA = Left(txtCorrectiveAction, Len(txtCorrectiveAction) - 2)
Else
    strCA = txtCorrectiveAction
End If
```

Then use strCA in your `insert` or `update` statement.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Skippy said, it is possible you may have CR or LF embedded in the string (i.e. you copy multiple lines).  The following code is just a sample to show how you can find where they occur, as well as two methods to remove.  Note the difference in removal ... the first only removes from the end of the string, the second removes all, regardless of where encountered in string.

```
' Sample code to find and replace CR, LF's
Dim tempNom As String
Dim tempCt  As Integer
Dim i       As Integer
Dim char    As String

tempNom = "Now is the time..." & vbCrLf  ' FOR TESTING. REMOVE WHEN LIVE!

' To find any CR or LF in string
For i = 1 To Len(tempNom)
    char = Mid(tempNom, i, 1)
    If Asc(char) = 13 Or Asc(char) = 10 Then
        Debug.Print "In position " & i & " of string: Found Asc(" & Asc(char) & ")"
    End If
Next i

' To remove either CR or LF from right of string
Do
    If right(tempNom, 1) = vbCr Or right(tempNom, 1) = vbLf Then
        tempNom = left(tempNom, Len(tempNom) - 1)
    Else
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop

' Replace all CR or LF anywhere in string
tempNom = "Now is the time..." & vbCrLf    ' FOR TESTING. REMOVE WHEN LIVE!
tempNom = Replace(tempNom, vbCr, "")
tempNom = Replace(tempNom, vbLf, "")
```